# Is it possible in android to show a persistent popup on notification?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I would like to know if it is possible to have a popup appear in the middle of the screen when recieving a notification and my app is on the background or closed. I would then want the popup to remain there untill clicked on. Is this possible on Android?

I am using flutter with firebase but I would just like to know if it is possible at all on android.

Comment: Yes, it is possible for Android. You can take a look at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html

Comment: But also when the app in on the background or closed?

Comment: By "background" you mean foreground right? Like the app being active?

Comment: No I mean background or closed. So on Android is it possible to have a notification that is a popup even when the app is closed

Comment: As far as I know, no, you can't have a popup notification appear in the middle of the screen if it's closed or in the background. In those cases, the notification will only be able to appear in the device tray.

Comment: No, it's not possible. When the app is terminated, the OS will handle showing a banner notification. Popups are handled by your app and it needs it to be in the foreground. You can have a look at onResume, onLaunch, onBackground, onMessage function provided by firebase messaging plugin https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it with a notification. But using https://pub.dev/packages/system_alert_window you can overlay custom UI over other apps. I ended up using the cloud messaging onBackgroundMessage to trigger this overlay.